# How to modify the output of tcpdump to be human-readable?

Tags: tcpdump

I have a tcpdump command:

```
tcpdump -i wlan0 dst port 80 and ! dst 192.168.1.201 and ! src 192.168.1.201 -vvv -s0 -w proba.txt
```

Which gives the following output:

```
root@SERVER:/tmp# egrep "GET|Host:" proba.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}{print $2}'
emaffia.hu
/
google.hu
/
www.google.hu
emaffia.hu
/textinputassistant/tia.png
www.google.hu
/logos/2011/pierre_de_fermat-2011-hp.jpg
www.google.hu
/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png
ssl.gstatic.com
/favicon.ico
www.google.hu
/
hwsw.hu
/js/mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js
www.hwsw.hu
```

How can I modify these lines to get this output?:

```
emaffia.hu/
google.hu/
www.google.hu
emaffia.hu/textinputassistant/tia.png
www.google.hu/logos/2011/pierre_de_fermat-2011-hp.jpg
www.google.hu/gb/images/b_8d5afc09.png
ssl.gstatic.com/favicon.ico
www.google.hu/
hwsw.hu/js/mootools-1.2.5.1-more.js
www.hwsw.hu
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into `tcpflow` instead, it decodes the protocol and produces human readable text streams. By default they go to a file but the `-c` flag prints it on the console. `tcpflow` is one of my favorite hidden gems.

Answer (score 0):

You pipe the output of your parsing command though `sed` - like this:

```
 egrep "GET|Host:" proba.txt | awk 'BEGIN {FS=" "}{print $2}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\//\//g'
```